# ROS2 C++ rclcpp::init(argc,argv);

Tags: ros2

Is there a software solution to retrieve in the node the information passed by argv[1]?
With Colcon build..., can we edit a precompilation file?

As part of my facial recognition project with ONNX
I want to be able to easily enter the name of the video file if proposed (otherwise camera)

Answer (score 2):

The existing solution would be to use [parameters](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Beginner-CLI-Tools/Understanding-ROS2-Parameters/Understanding-ROS2-Parameters.html)

These can be manually set at runtime or when launching through a [launchfile](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Intermediate/Launch/Creating-Launch-Files.html) using a [parameterfile](https://roboticsbackend.com/ros2-yaml-params/)

Alternatively, you can of course manually read argv[1] in your main or set values using the precompiler through cmake.